# Tensorflow: creating dataset/testing on my own images

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I adapt my code to import raw images from a directory, and then train and test off of the raw images?

I've created a program with train(), classify(), and main() functions.

main() only asks if you'd like to run the train() and classify() functions.

train() imports the specified dataset (I've used mnist handwritten numbers and fashion_mnist so far), sets the training model, and saves the model.

classify() loads the model saved by train(), shuffles the images, and iterates through the dataset making predictions.

If you test the code on tensorflow 1.14, it should work perfectly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle

data_set = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
model_data = 'fashion_mnist.model'
image_size = 28
class_names = {0:'t-shirt',1:'trouser',2:'pullover',3:'dress',4:'coat',5:'sandal',6:'shirt',7:'sneaker',8:'bag',9:'boot'}

def train():
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data_set.load_data()
    train_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(train_images, axis = 1) #makes data value 0-1
    test_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(test_images, axis = 1) #makes data value 0-1

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (image_size, image_size))) #flattens image
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu)) #amount of neurons
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax)) #probability distr

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs = 5)

    val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
    print(val_loss, val_acc)
    model.save(model_data)

def classify():
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data_set.load_data()
    train_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(train_images, axis = 1) #makes data value 0-1
    test_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(test_images, axis = 1) #makes data value 0-1

    shuffle(test_images)

    predict = 0
    for images in test_images:
        plt.imshow(test_images[predict], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
        plt.show()

        new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_data)
        predictions = new_model.predict([test_images])
        predict_class = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[predict])]
        print("\nprediction: ", predict_class)
        predict += 1

def main():
    run_train = int(input("\nrun training? yes:1 | no:0 "))
    if run_train == 1:
        train()
    else:
        pass

    classify_images = int(input("classify? yes:1 | no:0 "))
    if classify_images == 1:
        classify()
    else:
        pass

main()
```

I'd like to adapt the code so that the variable "data_set" points to a directory with subdirectories named after class_names, e.g.

```
animals > dogs  > dog1.jpg, dog2.jpg ...
        > cats  > cat1.jpg, cat2.jpg ...
        > birds > bird1.jpg, bird2.jpg ...
```

Each jpg image and label data would need to be stored in a numpy array similar to MNIST datasets. A create_data_set() function will probably be needed for all of this.

Finally, the classify() function will need to be adapted to test on raw images from directories.

I understand this is a lot to ask. I've attempted dozens of tutorials and read so much documentation over the past week, but I'm at a loss on importing custom image datasets to train a tensorflow model and test an image classifier. Please help with any info you have or where I can get started! Thank you!